# How to take a selected option with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm new here and I'm really sorry if the subject of this ticket do not have to be at this place.

I'm working on a PrestaShop website that use SMARTY. How could I display some products with the choice that a customer done in a `select` tag?

Can I do this with just PHP + HTML or do I need Javascript?

Here is my code :

```html
<div id="conseil">
 <h1 class="page-conseil">Page de conseil pour PC & PC portable Gamer</h1>
 <h2>Dites nous quel style de Gamer vous ètes, nous nous occupons du reste</h2>
 <div class="selection-gameplay">
  <p class="select-gameplay">Sélectionnez le type de joueur qui vous correspond</p>
  <select class="gameplay">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Sélectionnez</option>
   <option value="1">Casual (de temps en temps)</option>
   <option value="1">Normal (1 à 2h/jour)</option>
   <option value="1">Régulier (2 à 4h/jour)</option>
   <option value="1">Hard Core (>4h/jour)</option>
  </select>
  <p class="select-gameplay">Sélectionnez vos types de jeux</p>
  <select class="game">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Sélectionnez</option>
   <option value="1">MOBA & FPS peu gourmand (Counter Strike, LOL, DOTA, Heroes Of The Storm)</option>
   <option value="1">MMORPG (WOW, Blade and Soul), FPS (type overwatch, battlefield 3)</option>
   <option value="1">FPS poussé (Battlefield 1), Aventures</option>
   <option value="1">Tout en Ultra !</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="validation-btn">
  <button type="button" name="submit" class="validation-game">
   <span>Valider</span>
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to display 3 products that's correspond to the choice of the customer in select when he will hit the validate button.

My PHP's knowledge is not really high, if someone can guide, I don't want especially the answer just a way where I can work on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, have you got to resolved your issue? Have you tried my way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by php Html too, just add form tag for code block you have mention along with name properly to each select. When you click submit button form will be posted and give you array of values in $_POST global array, you can get value of single select by below syntax,

echo $_POST['game'];

Here "game" is name of one select form Element.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your inputs, text fields (if any), select options along with the final submit button. Give the form some id eg. `id="form1"` and in the select tag, write `form="form1"`. Also don't forget to give the action attribute to the form tag. It's basically a file where the data received from can be processed. If you set `action="process.php"`, you can retrieve the data of the select as `$some_variable=$_POST["name_of_select_tag"]`. Now you can use the variable to your need.